# Axios.post always sends null despite backend working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, axios

I am implementing an app where users can leave comments under blogposts.

However, when using axios.post - it sends out null everytime.

I have tried sending objects, strings and it is null everytime

I have tried using headers {'Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} and {'Content-Type: 'application/json} but nothing works.

The backend is working because comments send successfully on a POST request from POSTMAN.

I am guessing it is a bug with axios.

Is there a way to work around the bug?

**Service**

```
import axios from "axios";
const baseUrl = "www.localhost:3003/api/blogs";

        const newComment = async (content) => {
      const id = content.id
      const comment = content.comment
      const config = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      }
      const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/${id}/comments`, comment, config)
      return response.data
    }
```

**Reducer**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import blogService from '../services/blogs'
    
    const blogSlice = createSlice({
          name: 'blogs',
          initialState: [],
          reducers: {
    createBlog(state, action) {
              const content = action.payload
    
              const blogObject = {
                title: content.title,
                author: content.author,
                url: content.url,
                likes: 0,
                id: generateId()
              }
    
              state.push({
                title: content.title,
                author: content.author,
                url: content.url,
                likes: 0,
                id: generateId()
              })
    
              blogService.create(blogObject)
            }, 
    createComment(state, action) {
     const content = action.payload
     
    blogService.newComment(content)
    
    },
    newLike(state, action) {
            const id = action.payload
    
            const blogToChange = state.find(b => b.id === id)
    
            const changedBlog = { 
              ...blogToChange, 
              likes: blogToChange.likes + 1 
            }
    
            blogService.update(id, changedBlog)
    
            return state.map(blog =>
              blog.id !== id ? blog : changedBlog
            )
           },
    
    deleteBlog(state, action) {
      const id = action.payload
    
      blogService.remove(id)
    
      return state.filter(b => b.id !== id)
      
    },
          appendBlog(state, action) {
            state.push(action.payload)
          },
          setBlogs(state, action) {
            return action.payload
          }
        },
    })
```

**Blog**

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
    import blogService from '../services/blogs'
    import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
    import { setBlogs, newLike, createComment } from '../reducers/blogReducer'
    
    const SingleBlog = ({blogs }) => { 
    
    const [singleBlogs, setSingleBlogs] = useState([])
    const [comments, setComments] = useState('')
    const id = blogs.map(b => b.id)
      
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const voteLike = (id) => {
      dispatch(newLike(id))
    }
    
    const handleComment = (event) => {
    setComments(event.target.value)
    }
    
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      const comment = event.target.comment.value
    
      const id = singleBlogs.id
    
      const object = {comment: comment, id: id}
    
      dispatch(createComment(object))
    
    }
    
    const handleClick = () => {
      blogService
          .getAll().then(blogs => dispatch(setBlogs(blogs)))
    }
    
      useEffect(() => {
            blogService
              .getOne(id).then(singleBlogs => setSingleBlogs(singleBlogs)).then(singleBlogs => dispatch(setBlogs(singleBlogs)))
          }, [dispatch])
      
    
        
          if (!singleBlogs?.title) {
            return (
              <div><button onClick={handleClick}>Back</button></div>
            )
          }
        
         if (singleBlogs.user?.name) {
        return (
        <div>
    <h2>{singleBlogs.title}</h2>
    <p>URL: {singleBlogs.url}</p>
    <p>Likes: {singleBlogs.likes}</p><button onClick={() => voteLike(singleBlogs.id)}>Like</button>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Back</button>
    <p>added by: {singleBlogs.user.name}</p>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>Add Comment: <input name="comment" id="comment" value={comments} onChange={handleComment}></input><button type="submit">Add</button></form>
    <h4>Comments</h4>
    <ul>
      {singleBlogs.comments.map(s => <li><ul>{s}</ul></li>)}
    
    </ul>
    
        </div>
    )} else 
    return null
    }
    
    export default SingleBlog
```

**Backend**:

```
[{"comments":[],"title":"Blog Title","author":"J John","url":"www.url.com","user":{"username":"root","name":"Superuser","id":"628f969252b604bdb13b672e"},"id":"628f9b685bfa95ded0cb29cf","likes":0},{"comments":[],"title":"Blog Title","author":"J John","url":"www.url.com","user":{"username":"root","name":"Superuser","id":"628f969252b604bdb13b672e"},"id":"6298ba4da20133b892443f75","likes":0},{"comments":[],"title":"Passwords and tokens","author":"I Fleming","url":"www.iiii.com","user":{"username":"testuser","name":"testuser","id":"6298bef3c00dbef70a9f3c55"},"id":"6298cc365935ee8f873dd2cf","likes":0},{"comments":[],"title":"jjj","author":"jjj","url":"jjj","user":{"username":"jjj","name":"jjj","id":"629b18d3272af122ea7830f2"},"id":"629b194c5ad19d29b2d30910","likes":0},{"comments":[],"title":"You","author":"Program","url":"www.kkk.com","user":{"username":"kkk","name":"kkk","id":"629b19b15ad19d29b2d30915"},"id":"629b1a1e5ad19d29b2d3091d","likes":0},{"comments":[],"title":"Zoom","author":"Parzifal","url":"www.smorg.com","user":{"username":"kkk","name":"kkk","id":"629b19b15ad19d29b2d30915"},"likes":1,"id":"629b1b5fd8d110a6e5d4671e"},{"comments":[],"title":"Rank ","author":"J John","url":"www.rank.com","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"id":"629f53295cfed3eca2683add","likes":0},{"title":"Test Title With Update","author":"J John","url":"www.title.com","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"likes":3,"comments":["comment","comment",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"comment",null,null,"comment",null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"id":"62cc19b6df95af90c24418df"},{"comments":[],"title":"fdddd","author":"Daniel Harmann","url":"Daniel Harmann","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"likes":5,"id":"62d1760131423c5391b17a91"},{"comments":[],"title":"testtitle","author":"testauthor","url":"Testurl","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"id":"62e28bb6a2b3cf0a7e5a29dc","likes":0},{"comments":[],"title":"testtitle","author":"testauthor","url":"Testurl","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"id":"62e28bbda2b3cf0a7e5a29e0","likes":0},{"comments":[],"title":"testtitle","author":"testauthor","url":"Testurl","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"id":"62e28bd586a003866535deaa","likes":0},{"title":"Big Title","author":"Daniel Harmann","url":"Daniel Harmann","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"comments":[],"id":"62e3a74648a9f41983775caa","likes":0},{"title":"Big Title","author":"Daniel Harmann","url":"Daniel Harmann","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"comments":[],"id":"62e3a74948a9f41983775cae","likes":0},{"title":"ggggggg","author":"gggggggggg","url":"gggggggggg","user":{"username":"mmm","name":"mmm","id":"629b5b62d2afb19a39515c77"},"comments":[],"id":"62e3a75248a9f41983775cb8","likes":0}]
```

Comment: So you are saying when you're sending an axios POST req, you receive nothing on the backend whereas when you are sending a req using postman you receive data on the backend?

Comment: Correct. More specifically axios POST req receives "null", whereas on the backend it receives {"comment": "test comment"} successfully.

Comment: So in the backend you are not receiving the data , but the middleware function is getting executed?

Comment: The backend looks like this "comments": [null, null, null] I think it is getting executed.

Comment: Change baseUrl: "www.localhost:3003/api/blogs" to "http://localhost:3003/api/blogs"

Comment: Not a problem with baseUrl... the other axios.post route to post blogposts works.

Answer (score 3):

You should always send data in the form of an object {}

Change your axios POST request code to this,

```
const newComment = async (content) => {
  const id = content.id
  const comment = { comment: content.comment }
  const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/${id}/comments`, comment)
  return response.data
}
```

Comment: I think that was it, that is an important one to know for next time.